# To cut a line in two so that the squares of ... (geometric construction)

Tags: geometric-construction

> Cut a given straight line so that the sum of the square of one part and twice the square of the other part equals a given size.

Given a line of length $L$ which is cut in two pieces, lengths $x$ and $L-x$, I first thought of constructing the squares with sides $x$ and $\sqrt{2}(L-x)$ but I cannot relate the total area to a given length.

If $M$ is the given length the length to construct is
$$\frac{2L\pm\sqrt{3M-2L^2}}{3}$$
but I assume there is an easier way to solve this problem using only straight-edge and compass.

Any idea how to solve this problem? TIA.

Comment: It is a mistake to treat L and M as separate things. As for using a square and a compass, you need to divide a line segment into 3 parts and I don't know if that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Let the segment lengths be $(x,L-x)$ for total length $L.$

Total area
$$ A=x^2+2(L-x)^2= 3x^2-4xL+2L^2 \tag 1 $$

should be a constant or minimum / maximum when segmented at some $x$.

Differentiating to find location of partition,

$$ 6x-4L=0, x=\dfrac{2L}{3} \to A_{min}= \dfrac{2L^2}{3};$$

which is a ***function of $L.$*** It is easy to divide a line length  L =  OB into three equal parts. (A line drawn through any one end parallel lines from three equal segments as shown, take line trisected through D).

[image]

*However* in this problem the minimum is *a priori* specified to have  a *given size =S*, but not derivative driven $2 L^2/3$ minimum.  This is not possible without any ***modification*** of area expression in (1) accordingly, like in ..

$$  A=x^2+2(L-x)^2- \dfrac{2L^2}{3} +S  \tag2 $$

A numerical example for $ L=100, S=10000 $ gives desired area $=S$ at the calculated two thirds length.

*Geometric construction for physical Area Check*

Total area $ S= 10,000$ square units is fully accounted for as one square of $2L/3$ side and another five of $L/3$ side in rough sketch.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the square of one part plus twice the square of the other part equals the whole.

$$L=(x)^2+2(L-x)^2=2 L^2 - 4 L x + 3 x^2\\
\implies 3 x^2 - 4 L x + (2 L^2 - L) = 0$$

$$x=\frac{4L\pm\sqrt{16L^2-4(3)(2 L^2 - L)}}{2(3)}
=\frac{2L\pm \sqrt{L(3 - 2 L)}}{3}\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\iff 0\le  L\le \frac{3}{2}$$

Any value of $L$ in this range will work but the only (L,x) solutions that "contain" integers are
$$
(0,\space0)\qquad 
(1,\space1)\qquad (3/2,\space1)$$

So $$0^2+2(0-0)^2=0\qquad 
1^2+2(1-1)^2=1\qquad
 1^2+2(1.5-1)^2=1+2(.25)=1.5$$

Outside of this range, solutions are complex (containing imaginary parts),
i.e. $x\in\mathbb{C}$

$\textbf{Update}$ WolframAlpha shows the solution to be different from mine where I stayed in the limits.

$$(x)^2+2(L-x)^2-L=0,\quad L=414\\
\implies x = 276 + 5 i \sqrt{1518}\qquad L-x=138 + 5 i \sqrt{1518}$$

Multiplied back, it yields an enormous number for $L$, even with plus-minus the imaginary part [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28276+%2B+5+%5Csqrt%7B-1%7D+%5Csqrt%7B1518%7D%29%5E2+%2B%28414-%28276+%2B+5+%5Csqrt%7B-1%7D++%5Csqrt%7B1518%7D%29%29%5E2), and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28276+-+5+%5Csqrt%7B-1%7D+%5Csqrt%7B1518%7D%29%5E2+%2B%28414-%28276+-+5+%5Csqrt%7B-1%7D++%5Csqrt%7B1518%7D%29%29%5E2).

Comment: The solution should only involve straight-edge and compass. It is not about finding particular solution, but a general method for any two lines.

Comment: If you just want to trisect a line segment, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EGO6przl1k) shows one easy way to do that with a straight edge and compass. If you want it to meet your criteria, however, the line segment length $\;L\;$ must be measured in units where $0\le L \le \frac{3}{2}$ as indicated. in my answer

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but any rational number can be created using straight-edge and compass. E.g. $L=24$, $M=414$ gives $x=(48\pm3\sqrt{10})/3$. It is possible to construct $x$ and $x^2+2(L-x)^2=M$ as requested. The problem is to construct $x$ using tools, but no algebra.

Comment: You can go outside the limits but the results are complex as I said in my answer.
$$x^2$+(414-x)^2-414=0\\
\implies 2 x^2 - 828 x + 170982=0$$

$$x=\frac{828\pm\sqrt{828^2-4(2)(170982)}}{2(2)}=\frac{828\pm\sqrt{-682272}}{2(2)}\\
x=207\pm 3i\sqrt{4738}$$

Comment: I mentioned a link for trisecting a line segment if that's all you want to do but you may or may not meet the criteria of summing squares. If you can ingnore the imaginary multiplier, I am glad. I simply have not explored it.